# Import method in beforeEach

Tags: cypress

To run a set of tests I have to create an account, for that I have to use beforeEach(), but if I have a lot of test specs how to organize my test structure to avoid duplicates:

```
describe('my form', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/users/new')
    cy.get('#first').type('Johnny')
    cy.get('#last').type('Appleseed')
    cy.get('button').click()
  })
```

Is it possible to do something like this and just import `createAccount()` method everywhere:

```
describe('my form', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    createAccount()
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cypress [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html) and achieve this. Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createAccount', (firstName, lastName) => {
  cy.get('#first').type(firstName)
  cy.get('#last').type(lastName)
  cy.get('button').click()
})
```

Now in your tests, you can use it like:

```
describe('my form', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/users/new')
    cy.createAccount('Johnny','Appleseed')
  })
})
```